# Jquery - Check if a value of a select box changed from another JS code

Tags: jquery, onchange

I know that you can use the "onChange" method, but the onChange doesn't get fired if I change the value by code, like this :

```
<select id='selectBox' onChange='alert("changed")'>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="1">2</option>
<option value="1">3</option>
<select>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#selectBox').val('3');  
});
</script>
```

When the document loads, I would like the alert "changed" to popup... Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try firing the `change` event manually, like so:

```
$('#selectBox').val('3').change();
```

Comment: perfect! I have similar problem and this save me lots of time, thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use the jQuery change event and then call its when you change it from the code, example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#selectBox').change(function() {
    alert("changed")
  });

  $('#selectBox').val('3');
  $('#selectBox').change(); // this will  trigger change event
});
```